# почему отстает звук от видео MediaStream?

Tags: javascript

при попытке записи видеопотока в Chrome отстает звук от видео (буквально 0.3-0.4 секунды, но это прослушивается)
Подумал, что ошибка где-то у меня в коде, взял пример из документации (https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Medi...) - то же самое
Подскажите пожалуйста, почему так происходит и как можно исправить?

Comment: Эта ссылка скопирована не полностью.

Comment: А, видимо stackoverflow обрезал
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Recording_a_media_element

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, этот код не предусматривает отдельный разбор обработки аудио и видео, всё происходит вместе. Но можно попытаться в записанном видеофайле исправить отставание звука, открыв этот файл в каком-то видеоредакторе.